# Will you look over my HTML email and tell me why this <td> is crooked?

Tags: html, css

[image: The image on the bottom right is crooked, How do I straighten it?]

This is an HTML email I'm coding for practice, I can't get this last image to straighten out.

Here is the HTML for this table.

```css
.smallimg {
  width: 295px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: auto;
}

.bold {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 1000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<table width='600' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Stratocaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' target='_blank'><img src='stratocaster.jpg' class='smallimg'></a>
        <div class='bold'> <b>Stratocaster <sup class='trademark'>®</sup> <p> Models</b>
          <a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Stratocaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' class='bold'>
            <p><a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Stratocaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' class='red'> Shop Now</p></a></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Telecaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' target='_blank'><img src='telecaster.jpg' class='smallimg'></a>
        <div class='bold'> <b>Telecaster <sup class='trademark'>®</sup> <p> Models</b>
          <p><a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Telecaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' class='red'> Shop Now</p></a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Jazzmaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' target='_blank'><img src='jazzmaster.jpg' class='smallimg'></a>
        <div class='bold'> <b>Jazzmaster <sup class='trademark'>®</sup> <p> Models </b>
          <p><a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Jazzmaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' class='red'>&nbsp; Shop Now</p></a></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- Here is the code for the bass img -->
        <a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Basses.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' target='_blank'><img src='BASS.jpg' class='smallimg'></a>
        <div class='bold'><b>Basses</b>
          <p><a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Basses.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' class='red'> Shop Now</p></a></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you have a lost p tag : `<sup class='trademark'>®</sup> <p> Models </b>` but not in the last cell.

Comment: Your opening and closing `p` and `a` tags are mismatched: `<p><a>...</p></a>` should be `<p><a>...</a></p>`

Comment: a usefull online tool :https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea insert your table code inside the body tag , and see the warnings ...

Answer (score 2):

The table-cells automatically align themselves.
Because the left-bottom cell is larger in height, the one next to it centers itself.

You can fix this by adding `vertical-align: top;` to your `td`!

Comment: actually, there typo in the HTML code, this is what should be fixed first . ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alright gang I fixed it! Here is the final result if you're curious.

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>

        <tr> 
            <td>
                    <a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Stratocaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' target ='_blank'><img src='stratocaster.jpg' class='smallimg'></a> <div class='bold'> <b>Stratocaster <sup class='trademark'>®</sup> <p> Models</p></b> <a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Stratocaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' class='bold'></a> <p><a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Stratocaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' class='red'> Shop Now</p></a></div> 
            </td>
            <td>
                    <a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Telecaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85'target ='_blank'><img src='telecaster.jpg' class='smallimg'></a> <div class='bold'> <b>Telecaster <sup class='trademark'>®</sup> <p> Models</p></b> <p><a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Telecaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' class='red'> Shop Now</a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                    <a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Jazzmaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85'target ='_blank'><img src='jazzmaster.jpg' class='smallimg'></a> <div class='bold'> <b>Jazzmaster <sup class='trademark'>®</sup> <p> Models </p></b><p><a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Jazzmaster-Guitars.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' class='red'>&nbsp; Shop Now</p></a></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- Here is the code for the bass img -->
                    <a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Basses.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85'target ='_blank'><img src='BASS.jpg' class='smallimg'></a> <div class='bold'><b>Basses</b> <p><a href='https://www.guitarcenter.com/Fender-American-Ultra-Basses.gc?source=4TP9LHBA&dtm_em=d6a9d8b391c15fbb2e0fb42983408d85' class='red'> Shop Now </a><p>&nbsp;</p></div>  
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
td{
    vertical-align: top;
}

.smallimg{
    width:295px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:0;
    border-style:none;
    padding:20px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align: top;

}

.bold{
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-family:'Montserrat',helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight:1000;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:0;
}
```